# Timer ticks twice per second then thrice when I reuse it (I never change the interval)

Tags: c#, timer, windows-phone-8.1

This is supposed to be a simple game where you lose 1 life each time you take more than the time allowed for each question you answer. I've searched for a code to set up my timer, found multiple ways to do it and ended up using the one below.

At first I noticed **timer_Tick()** runs **twice** each second instead of just once. So I had to increase the **ElapsedTime** by **0.5f** instead of **1f** to get the correct elapsed time.. It works perfectly until I have to restart the timer (when I load a new question). When I do that, **timer_Tick()** runs **three** times per second instead of two.. Which means the seconds counter decreases by **1.5f** instead of 1f each second. I would like to know what's causing this and how I can fix it. Thanks in advance.

```
public void Start_timer(float Interval)
{
  ElapsedTime = 0f;
  timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
  timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Interval);
  bool enabled = timer.IsEnabled;
  timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    ElapsedTime += 0.5f; //I had to set this to 0.5f to get the correct reading as timer_Tick runs 2 times per second..
    TimeT.Text = "Time: " + Convert.ToString(QTime - ElapsedTime);
    if (ElapsedTime >= QTime && Lives == 0){
        timer.Stop();
        AnswerTB.IsEnabled = false;
        //GameOver
    }
    else if (ElapsedTime >= QTime && Lives != 0)
    {
        ElapsedTime = 0f;
        Lives--;
        LivesT.Text = "Lives: " + Convert.ToString(Lives);
        timer.Stop();
        LoadQuestion(); //This includes a Start_timer(1) call and I never change the 1 second interval.
    }
}
```

Comment: Each time you start timer you add additional event by this line: `timer.Tick += timer_Tick;`, so the first time it will work ok, the second time you invoke the method, you will have two events subscribed and so on - I suppose this is the problem. Specify the event and interval only when you create the timer.

Comment: what happens when you debug the code ...

Comment: @Romasz I'm quite new to C# but I can see you're probably right, I'll try fixing it now. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I have no idea how to fix it.. I thought timer.Stop() stops the timer_Tick() event?

Comment: Before you do timer.Tick += timer_Tick;, do this: timer.Tick -= timer_Tick;

Comment: Can you just move the line `timer.Tick += timer_Tick;` to your constructor, after you create the timer `DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();`?

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you all. I'm sorry for posting such a simple question but I'm new to the language and was running out of thoughts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you resubscribe to the Tick event each time you start the timer. If you don't unsubscribe when the timer stops, you end up firing the event several times for each tick. Just subscribe to the Tick event once, after creating the timer event and leave it at that. So move the line

```
timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
```

to the part of the code where you create the timer. Then you should be able to stop and start the timer without receiving multiple events.